# Pattern matching using current object

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to match an `Option`, and test to see if it's a `Some` containing the object making the call. So the code I want to write looks like this:

```
methodReturningOption() match {
    case Some(this) => doSomething()
    case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

but that fails to compile, with the error

> '.' expected but ')' found

I also tried using `` Some(`this`) `` which gives the error

> not found: value this

I can make it work if I add a variable which refers to `this`

```
val This = this
methodReturningOption() match {
    case Some(This) => doSomething()
    case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

but that looks ugly and seems like an unpleasant workaround. Is there an easier way to pattern match with `this` as an argument?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you could try this:

```
methodReturningOption() match {
  case Some(x) if x == this => doSomething()
  case _ => doSomethingElse()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `this` is considered a special keyword and can't be used in that context.

Jack Leow's solution is probably the best - I'd recommend going with that since it's much more explicit. However as an alternative you can also create a variable point to 'this' using the following syntax. (Note the `self =>` on the first line)

```
class Person { self =>
    def bla() = methodReturningOption() match {
        case Some(`self`) => ???
        case _          => ???
    }
}
```

This doesn't really answer the question, it's just a potential alternative syntax that may be useful to you.